# How to get a Calendar in a specific timezone using Jackson?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, jackson, timezone

I'm trying to figure out how to serialize and deserialize a Calendar object with a specific timezone.  I'm thinking it's reasonable that Jackson can respect my timezone and allow me to keep my Calendar instances in a specified timezone.  It works for serialize but not deserialize.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class JacksonTimeZoneTest2 {
    public Calendar time;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        JacksonTimeZoneTest2 test = new JacksonTimeZoneTest2();
        test.time = new java.util.GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 1);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
        mapper.setDateFormat(sdf);
        ByteArrayOutputStream serialized = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mapper.writeValue(serialized, test);
        String json = serialized.toString();
        if ( json.contains("CEST") ) {
          System.out.println("It serialized to CET timezone (CEST) [" + serialized.toString() + "]");
        }
        JacksonTimeZoneTest2 test2 = mapper.readValue(serialized.toString(), JacksonTimeZoneTest2.class);
        if ( ! "CET".equals(test2.time.getTimeZone().getID()) ) {
          System.out.println("Problem! It deserialized to [" + test2.time.getTimeZone().getID() + "] instead of CET");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get the following output:

```
It serialized to CET timezone (CEST) [{"time":"Mon, 01 Sep 2014 08:00:00 CEST"}]
Problem! It deserialized to [UTC] instead of CET
```

I also tried with a JsonFormat annotation specifying a timezone, and I got the same result.  I logged that as [an issue against Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1378).

Comment: As usual, the first thing is to ensure you are using an up-to-date version of Jackson. Currently, at least 2.7(.7), if not 2.8(.3).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to state that I'm testing with 2.8.3

Answer (score 2):

It works if you set the mapper's timezone.

```
public class JacksonTest {
    public Calendar time;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        JacksonTest obj = new JacksonTest();
        obj.time = new java.util.GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 1);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        // Can even remove the sdf TimeZone...
        //sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(sdf);
        mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream serialized = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mapper.writeValue(serialized, obj);

        JacksonTest obj2 = mapper.readValue(serialized.toString(), JacksonTest.class);

        System.out.println(serialized);
        //{"time":"Mon, 01 Sep 2014 09:00:00 CEST"}

        System.out.println(obj2.time.getTimeZone().getID());
        //CET

    }
}
```

But I guess that doesn't answer your question as to why the deserializer ignores the Calendar's timezone while the serializer keeps it intact.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know.  I doesn't fully solve my problem because I'm writing a library to persist objects to/from a db.  I don't own the objects--users of my library do.  It's possible devs might want to persist their objects with various timezones in tact, so they may not know before deserializing an object what timezone to pass to mapper.setTimeZone.

Comment: With Jackson 2.9.5, `objectMapper.setTimeZone()` worked whereas `objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().getDateFormat().setTimeZone()` or `objectMapper.getDateFormat().setTimeZone()` did not.